# Creation of duplicate contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development

I have a contract `A` and values stored in it. Now, if I want to create a contract `B`, which uses all the values stored in contract `A` and do some manipulations over there, how can I implement it? i.e., how can I create a duplicate of the contract `A` in `B`?

Answer (score 2):

The values stored, in storage, by the `contractA` instance can only by manipulated by the code of the `contractA` instance. This is how the EVM works, whether your contract was compiled from Solidity or any other language.

So your *same* code, at instance `contractB` cannot directly manipulate the stored values of `contractA`. OTOH, it can call `contractA` to do some actions.

Separately, you may want to look into Solidity libraries and their use of `DELEGATECALL` to have `contractA` use the code found at `contractB` in order to do some actions on `contractA`'s storage. Note that it is still `contractA` that is in control.